# process pipeline in c#

Tags: c#, process

I have a loop that spawn new process to run some ".exe" files. And I capture
the output of those ".exe" files to my textbox. In order to capture the outputs
right away, I can't use process.waitforexit() method. The problem I have right 
now is if the previous process took a long time to run, a second process will run
regardless if the previous one finished or not. This messed up my outputs.

Is there a way for me to insert the processes into a queue structure so it 
can be run in a sequential order?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Sure:

```
Queue<Process> processes = GetProcesses();
while(processes.Count > 0) {
    Process process = processes.Dequeue();
    // execute process and capture output
}
```

Here's MSDN on [`Queue(T)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx).

Comment: If I understand correctly, getProcesses creates an array of new Process components and associates them with existing process resources. However, I just want the process I created in the loop to be in the queue. How should I initialize the queue in this case?

Comment: `GetProcesses` is your function for populating the queue. Use `Queue.Enqueue` to add the processes that you create to the queue.

Answer (score 0):

You could also run the processes parallelly in threads and queue only the output.

However, you would have to use a more complicated locking and notification system.